# Null check operator used on a null value in flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

In the drawer, I'm showing the user's email address. but null error is showing !
i am also adding ? this sign same error but null

```
final email = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email;


   Center(
      child: Text(
        '$email',
        style: const TextStyle(fontWeight:   FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.indigo),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: `!`  is used when you are sure its not null. You have to either check the value is null or not before using the `!`  operator or use `?`  operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible your `currentUser` is null. Instead of forcing with bang`!`, you can do a null check or accept null value like

```dart
final email = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email;
```

Also you     can provide default value like

```dart
final email = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email ?? "Got null user";
```

Find more about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: Null text is displayed in place of the email id.

Comment: that's indicates the instance of firebaseAuth is not able to fetch the data of currentUser